# Connection issue with Jenkins within Docker on RaspberryPi 3 (rpi-jenkins) when cloning a Bitbucket Git Repo

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, bitbucket, raspberry-pi3

I'm currently playing around with Jenkins on Raspi within Docker (using [dilgerm/rpi-jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/r/dilgerm/rpi-jenkins/) image).
Now I have a problem with connecting to a Bitbucket Git repository.
When entering the repository url, I get (the commonly known) "Failed to connect to repository"

When using **https** and providing credentials (via Jenkins Credentials store), I get the error.

When using **ssh** and configuring the keys properly, I get the same error.

Now I am wondering if I have to configure the ssh-key **withing** the docker container (for the Jenkins user?). Currently, I have implemented the key on the hosting Raspi itself.

Or may it be required to configure/publish the ssl port of the Docker container on startup (-p parameter)?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think that 'rpi-jenkins' has a problem with Git in general, wether it is Github or Bitbucket, I have the same image and same problem...